# How to get GPS location in react-native-maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, react-native

My react-native app is using [`react-native-maps`](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps) to display a Google Maps and a marker. A styled `View` is used as the location marker that has a fixed position on the device screen.

**Question:** How can we get the GPS coordinates (lat/lng) of the marker, at say the bottom left corner of the `<View style={styles.marker}>` component?

```
<MapView
    ref='map'
    initialRegion={{
        latitude: LATITUDE,
        longitude: LONGITUDE,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
    }}
    showsUserLocation={true}
></MapView>

<View style={styles.markerContainer}>
    <View style={styles.marker}>
    </View>
</View>
```

**styles**

```
var deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
StyleSheet.create({
    markerContainer: {
        bottom: deviceHeight/2.2,
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
    },
})
```

Comment: I think you should use react-native-maps own marker component https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/marker.md and not to absolute position it by yourself

Answer (score 0):

```
<MapView
    ref='map'
    initialRegion={{
        latitude: LATITUDE,
        longitude: LONGITUDE,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
    }}
    showsUserLocation={true}


**onUserLocationChange={(e)=>console.log(e.nativeEvent.coordinate)}**
></MapView>

<View style={styles.markerContainer}>
    <View style={styles.marker}>
    </View>
</View>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thank you for your contribution. Code only dumps are discouraged on SO. Consider an `edit` to highlight important bits, & explain how/why they solve the OP's issue. Quality answers receive more upvotes over time as future visitors learn something from your post that they can apply to their own code base.